# Form resets stored components upon submission

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to make an editable piece of display text, such that:

- The text itself is not a textarea/input, it is just standard text
- Clicking on the text will open a text area and edit button, which allows you to edit the text
- Clicking the edit button will update the display text, and hide the textarea/edit button (display:none)

**I have implemented every part of this, and now have a bug where any time I hit the 'edit' button, all of the text components are erased from the page entirely.**

To achieve this, I have a `Page` component which stores a series of `EditableText` components (you can add more `EditableText` components via a `+` button at the bottom of the page):

```js
const Page = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles()
  var [components, setComponents] = useState([])
  var [displayButton, setDisplayButton] = useState(false)

  const toggleButton = () => {
    displayButton = !displayButton
    setDisplayButton(displayButton)
  }

  const addCaution = () => {
    setComponents(components.concat(<Caution />))
    displayButton = !displayButton
    setDisplayButton(displayButton)
  }

  const addImportant = () => {
    setComponents(components.concat(<Important />))
    displayButton = !displayButton
    setDisplayButton(displayButton)
  }

  const opbutton = (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={addHeader}>header</Button>
      <Button onClick={addText}>text</Button>
      <Button onClick={addCaution}>caution</Button>
      <Button onClick={addImportant}>important</Button>
    </div>
  )

  return (
    <div className={classes.page}>
      {components}
      {displayButton ? opbutton : null}
      <Button onClick={toggleButton}>+</Button>
    </div>
  )
```

The `EditableText` components are added into an array via `useState`.

Here is the code for the `EditableText`:

```js
const EditableText = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const { inputs, handleInputChange, handleSubmit } = useSubmit()
  var [displayText, setDisplayText] = useState("click here to add notes!")
  var [showBox, setShowBox] = useState(false)
  var [showClickArea, setClickArea] = useState(true)
  const inputBox = (
    <form
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row", width: "100%" }}
    >
      <textarea
        type="text"
        name="displayText"
        className={classes.textbox}
        onChange={handleInputChange}
        value={inputs}
        style={{ borderColor: props.border }}
        onSubmit={"return inputs"}
      >
        {inputs}
      </textarea>
      <Button id="editbutton" type="submit" className={classes.button}>
        edit
      </Button>
    </form>
  )

  const toggleEdit = () => {
    showClickArea = !showClickArea
    setClickArea(showClickArea)
    showBox = !showBox
    setShowBox(showBox)
  }

  const clickArea = (
    <div
      style={{ width: "80%", height: "200%", position: "absolute" }}
      onClick={toggleEdit}
    />
  )

  return (
    <div>
      {showClickArea ? clickArea : null}
      <div className={classes.background} style={{ color: props.color }}>
        {inputs}
        <div>{showBox ? inputBox : displayText}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

You may notice the use of `useSubmit` which is a custom hook:

```js
  const useSubmit = (callback) => {
    const [input, setInput] = useState({})

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
      callback()
    }

    const handleInputChange = (event) => {
      event.persist()
      setInput((input) => ({
        ...input,
        [event.target.name]: [event.target.value],
      }))
    }

    return (handleSubmit, handleInputChange, input)
  }
```

What I figure is that this may be an issue with the custom hook, or the use of `form` and `submit`. I think `form` is supposed to clear the page once submitted. But I'm not entirely sure. Any idea how to prevent this?

Comment: I would get rid of the `<form>` and also use `type="button"`

Comment: @charlietfl checked that out and still no luck. It seems that `inputs` is not actually being propagated with any text

Comment: Can you put a demo together in codesandbox or stackblitz or other sandbox site?

Comment: After some long hours, I figured it out and moved on! Didn't need any of the hooks. Will post an update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by creating a function and an 'edit' variable:

```js
 function setDisplayState() {
    if (edit === false) {
      return (
        <div
          style={{
            color: props.color,
            fontWeight: props.weight ? props.weight : 400,
            fontSize: props.size ? props.size : 14,
          }}
        >
          {displayText}
        </div>
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <textarea
            className={classes.textbox}
            style={{ color: props.color }}
            value={displayText}
            onChange={(e) => {
              displayText = e.target.value
              setDisplayText(displayText)
            }}
          />
          <Button className={classes.button} onClick={saveChange}>
            save
          </Button>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
```